Is it safe to run electrical wiring externally in metallic conduits, and can I route Ethernet cables alongside them?
I've inherited a poorly executed electrical installation in my apartment. Some cables are directly embedded in concrete without conduit, and in several places, the conduits are blocked and cables can't be replaced. The installation is failing, and I'm currently using extension cords in many areas.
Redoing the entire installation by burying new cables in the concrete walls is prohibitively expensive. I'm considering running new electrical wiring externally using industrial-style metallic conduits or cable channels.
Are there any issues (besides aesthetics) with running electrical cables externally in metallic conduits or cable channels in a residential setting?
I also have a wired 1 Gb Ethernet cable that needs to run the length of the apartment along the same route as the power cables. Will running Ethernet cables alongside power cables cause any interference or other issues?
Any advice or considerations would be greatly appreciated.
Location - Europe/Romania - I'm not aware of any codes against this, but I haven't studied that much the issue.

In most locations (I can't speak to Romania specifically) this is perfectly normal and legal, if typically unusual for residences as it's considered "too industrial looking" but it's perfectly safe - safer, in fact, than common residential wiring practices in most areas (but likely equivalent in most apartment building construction, which does tend to be more carefully done due to higher risk to others, in most areas; but generally hidden in the walls, floors and ceilings for residences, as your original wiring is.)
With the power wiring in conduit, the ethernet can follow the same path and does not need separation. Code (USA being what I know) required separation of power and ethernet is for electrical safety. Cautious designers of large network installations do like a great deal of separation, but in point of observed fact, the fact that ethernet is differential signals on twisted pairs operating at high  frequencies means concerns about noise from 50 Hz or 60 Hz power lines are vastly overstated. The system is designed to reject outside interference, and it does.
You could use a fiber optic cable if you had concerns of interference, but practically speaking unless there is a huge amount of high frequency interference on the power lines there's virtually nothing coming off them that will affect ethernet, and even less if they are contained within metallic conduit, which acts as a shield. Do NOT run low voltage (Ethernet) cables inside the same conduits that line voltage power cables run in. For that, all-dielectric fiber optic cable is the only safe/acceptable choice.

While that's true in theory, at work we've had more than one case where power and Ethernet running along the length of a single wall still caused issues that disappeared as soon as the same cable was moved further away...
